# Test new controller action with rspec feature test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, mail-form

I'm using the [mail form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form) to handle my website's contact form. I'm using rspec and capybara in my testing environment. I'm encountering an error when trying to test the contact form page. The new action of the contacts controller does create a new instance of the contact model, however I don't know how to do that in rspec to fix the reason for the failure.

**The failed test output:**

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"contacts", :format=>nil} missing required keys: []
```

**contact_form_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Comtact Form Email", :type => :feature do
  scenario "User sends email via contact form" do
    visit contacts_path

    fill_in 'Name', :with => 'Jony Ive'
    fill_in 'Email', :with => 'jony@apple.com'
    fill_in 'Subject', :with => 'Subject Here'
    fill_in 'Message', :with => 'Message'

    click_button 'Send Message'

    expect(page).to have_text("Thank you for your message.")

    last_email.to.should include('help@everydayrails.com') 
    last_email.from.should include('aaron@everydayrails.com')
  end 
end
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
      redirect_to contacts_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Your message could not be sent.'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/contacts',     to: 'contacts#new',             via: 'get'
resources :contacts, only: [:create]
```

**Routes output**

```
contacts GET             /contacts(.:format)     contacts#new
         POST            /contacts(.:format)     contacts#create
```

Comment: Should it be `visit new_contacts_path`?  Kind of tired here but that would be my guess.  You could run `rake routes` to be sure about the routes.

Comment: The match '/contacts' is just a cleaner version of new_contacts_path. Even when I try new_contacts_path I get the exact same error.

Comment: Seeing the routes. You have two routes defined for new method. One with match keyword and other with resources keyword.  With match. For new. The path would be /contacts and with resource the path would be /contact/new. Can you pls post output of rake routes

Comment: @Hemali I removed one of the new methods from my routes path to clean things up. However, I'm still getting the same error.